# Symfony - causes error "Expected argument of type" with using framework Sonata

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here function is overriding on based framework called by name Sonata which is building admin template :

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper){
$formMapper->add('owner', 'sonata_type_model_list',
    array(
        'class' => 'XYZXBundle:ContestUser',
        'btn_add'       => false,      //Specify a custom label
        'btn_list'      => 'Search',     //which will be translated
        'btn_delete'    => false,             //or hide the button.
        'btn_catalogue' => 'SonataNewsBundle', //Custom translation domain for buttons
    ), array(
        'placeholder' => 'No owner selected'
    ))
    }
```

Object structure:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @var XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser
 */
protected $owner;
```

Happens when i tried to insert new row.

Error stacktrace:

> Expected argument of type
>   "XYZ\XBundle\Entity\XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser",
>   "XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser" given` in
>   vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php
>   at line 254

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to use like that below, but still causes the same error.

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser")
 or
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ContestUser")
```

**UPDATE 2**

file XYZ\X\Entity\Contest.php

```
<?php

namespace XYZ\XBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

/**
 * XYZ\XBundle\Entity\Contest
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contests")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ListRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Contest
```

XYZ\X\Entity\ContestUser.php

```
<?php

namespace XYZ\XBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="contest_users")
 */
class ContestUser extends BaseUser
{
```

Namespaces are still valid ok, but only with type `sonata_type_model_list` causes this error.

Comment: `targetEntity="ContestUser"`

Comment: @malcolm, that doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found stupid my fail and i had:

```
public function setOwner(XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser $owner){}
```

that code works for me:

```
public function setOwner(\XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser $owner){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect namespace in your mapping annotation in line:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser")
```

It means a namespace relative to the current one.

You should either add a backslash at the beginning to make it an absolute namespace.

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\XYZ\XBundle\Entity\ContestUser")
```

or use simply only class name as both current and `ContestUser` classes seem to be in the same namespace:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ContestUser")
```

Comment: That would mean that you also have that issue somewhere else. Find all usages of this class and check if the namespace is correct.